# Received udp data rate measurement

Tags: networking, udp, rate

I want to measure the udp packets rate which I receive on my pc on a particular port. Is there any application which can show the received udp throughput and its variation with the passage of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to sniff the traffic on your host with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), filter by a certain UDP port and then access to the statistical menu.

Look at this example output:

[image]

Follow this link for a brief explanation of Wireshark statical capabilities: [Wireshark Statistics](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Statistics)

Comment: Would you mind to accept the answer? ^^ Have a nice day buddy